# Why can I not apply l'hopital's rule to this sum?

Tags: calculus, limits

There's this limit below that I have to evaluate.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+2}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+n}} \right]
$$
There's probably a way to evaluate it by interpreting it as a Riemann sum of some sort but my current approach is first to factor out $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and then apply L'hopital's rule.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+i} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+i}}{n}
$$
Now this is the step that confuses me, when l'hopital's rule is applied and using demons to graph the two functions I get [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8hqeklj0wa).

[image]

These are clearly two different limits, what's going on here? At first I thought something funny was going on and demons was turning the $x$ above the sigma into a $1$ but that isn't the case as the graph of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{x}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+i}}\right)\right)}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}$ is the same.

Comment: If you increase $x$ by $1$ you get an extra term in the summation, so if the derivative of the sum is at all meaningful then it not the sum of the derivatives:   $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{x}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+i}}\right)\right) \not = $ $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{x}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+i}}\right)\right)$

Comment: L'Hopital's rule applies only to functions of a real variable. Your numerator is defined only for integer values $n \ge 1$.

Comment: The function is only defined for $n$ an integer.

Comment: What is happening with the example without the square root splatted in the middle of your question?

Comment: @Henry so does there exist a way to apply l'hopital's rule to the sum?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Could you explain then why the sum with the derivative inside doesn't work? It seems that it should work because you take the derivative of each term rather than taking the derivative of the sum.

Comment: Let $f(x,i)=\frac1{\sqrt{x+i}},$ and $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{x} f(x,i)$ What does $g(3.5)$ mean? Does it just mean $f(3.5,1)+f(3.5,2)+f(3.5,3)?$ Then $g$ won't even be continuous at $x=4.$

Comment: Handwaving, increasing $x$ by $1$ adds an extra term of about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}}$ and if you add this to your sum of derivatives before doing the division then this increases the result by $\sqrt{2}$.  This is the limit of the gap between your red and black lines on your chart.

Answer (score 0):

**For your curiosity**

*Probably not very kosher but, in **this** case, it works.*

$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+i}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n} }\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n+i}}$$ Using  the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function)
$$S_n=\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},n+1\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},2 n+1\right)}{\sqrt{n} }$$ Both numerator and denominator tend to infinity.

Switching to the real domain, we then look for
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},x+1\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},2 x+1\right)}{\sqrt{x} }$$

Using L'Hospital rule we have
$$\frac {\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2},2 x+1\right)-\frac{1}{2} \zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2},x+1\right) } {\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} }=\sqrt{x} \left(2 \zeta \left(\frac{3}{2},2 x+1\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2},x+1\right)\right)$$ which gives the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\int\limits_{x=n+i}^{n+i+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{x}}\, dx\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+i}}\le \int\limits_{x=n+i-1}^{n+i} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{x}}\, dx$$

so

$$\int\limits_{x=n+1}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{x}}\, dx\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+2}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+n}} \le \int\limits_{x=n}^{2n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{x}}\, dx$$

i.e. sandwiched between $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}(\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{n+1})$ and $\sqrt{8}-2 \approx 0.8284$.  The lower bound increases towards the upper bound as $n$ increases, so the limit of the sum is $$\sqrt{8}-2 \approx 0.8284$$ shown by the red line on your chart.